# jnius Android Intent.putExtra() expects String value but Boolean/Long is required

Tags: python, java, android, android-intent, kivy

I'm writing an app with Kivy and Jnius Python. I want to execute some `INSERT_ACTION` with an android.content.Intent.

Currently I have:

```py
from jnius import autoclass

Intent = autoclass("android.content.Intent")
Calendar = autoclass("java.util.Calendar")
CalendarContract = autoclass("android.provider.CalendarContract")
Events = autoclass("android.provider.CalendarContract$Events")
JS = autoclass("java.lang.String")
# JB = autoclass("java.lang.Boolean")

intent = Intent()
date = Calendar.getInstance()
date.set(2022, 5, 26)
intent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, JS("Some Title"))
intent.putExtra(
    CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY,
    JS("true"),
)
intent.putExtra(
    CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
    JS(str(date.getTimeInMillis())),
)

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
currentActivity = cast("android.app.Activity", PythonActivity.mActivity)
currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
```

It does open the calendar to save the event, but uses a default time and is not all day. What works however is the title. That one is working like expected.
This throws the error: `Key allDay expected Boolean but value was a java.lang.String`

The thing is that `CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY` needs a Boolean Value. However if if try something like `intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, JB("true"))` (where `JB = autoclass("java.lang.Boolean")`) I get the error:

```
File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1145, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__
File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 851, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
File "jnius/jnius_conversion.pxi", line 78, in jnius.jnius.populate_args
File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 205, in jnius.jnius.check_assignable_from
jnius.jnius.JavaException: Invalid instance of 'java/lang/Boolean' passed for a 'java/lang/String'
```

this seems due to the Fact that `.putExtra()` only accepts String Values.

**What I tried**

`intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, cast("java.lang.Boolean", JS("true"))` -> 'java/lang/Boolean' passed for a 'java/lang/String'

`intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, cast("java.lang.CharSequence", JS("true"))` -> 'Key allDay expected Boolean but value was a java.lang.String'

`intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, True)` -> 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean'

Has anyone an idea how to resolve this conflict or should I raise an Issue with kivy?

Comment: Add minimal working example

Comment: I would love to, but I don't have one. Can you maybe specify what is missing for you to find an answer?

Comment: Basically what does work is anything that requires a String and where I pass a String, like this: `intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, JS(tool))`

Comment: For the answer, I need a minimal runable example, this will greatly help me to give an answer.

Comment: I added some extra lines and commented what works and what not plus relevant lines from the traceback. Is that more of what you where looking for?

Comment: Look, a minimal working example is code that I can just copy and paste, then run, compile it, etc. If you do this, you will get an answer to the question sooner, because the answerer does not have to write a test application from scratch

Comment: Understood, but I fear it's not just easy since its an android app written in python. You can copy the `main.py` from here: https://github.com/bagdenaj/TidyTools/tree/main/tools-app

Comment: But you need to build the app/ apk  with bulldozer (using the `buildozer.spec`  and then run it on an android emulator. Thank you for your help in any case!

Comment: OK, I will try to build it

Comment: Let me know, if you need help with building ;)